# How to convert Java Object to ASN.1 stream?

Tags: java, asn.1

I wonder if there is a simple way to convert a java object to a ASN.1 byte stream. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is this project, too: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/

and http://harmony.apache.org/subcomponents/classlibrary/asn1_framework.html

Answer (score 3):

I use http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/ and it is working quite good for me. It's very simple and easy to use, just read the [development guide](http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/BinaryNotes.pdf) and you will understand very fast.

Comment: I'm not able to run bnotes , I got errors : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bn/coders/IASN1PreparedElement
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ...

Comment: depends on what you tried to do, can be more specific? did write an asn1 file first, did you compile it, where does your error appear? in the meanwhile I changed to a commercial solution `asn1c` which is supporting more ASN1 notations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you first need to get the concept of what ASN.1 is, since you say you are new to it.

With ASN.1 you specify the types that may be used to form a message.  When this is combined with a defined set of encoding rules, you then have a full specification of the bytes that constitute a message.

Databinding tools (such as one my company, Objective Systems, sells) can take an ASN.1 specification and then generate Java classes that model the types defined in the ASN.1, and which include methods to encode/decode the modeled data, according to a defined set of encoding rules (BER, PER), to bytes.

It doesn't really make sense to speak of taking an arbitrary Java object and turning it into an ASN.1 byte stream because you lack two key pieces: the ASN.1 that specifies what will be in the message and the selection of encoding rules.  In theory, I suppose someone could come up with a standard according to which arbitrary Java objects would be serialized to ASN.1, but I'm not aware of such, and that would be rather different from what the databinding tools do.

I hope I've made sense.

Comment: True. Maybe the author of the question wanted to ask how to transform a Java class into a ASN.1 file.

Answer (score 0):

I see java library from at least the below

1. http://www.chaosinmotion.com/asn1.m
2. [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Comment: Example for bouncycastle: new ASN1OutputStream(<byteStream>).writeObect(<object>);

Comment: this gives me a "object not asn1encodable" exception

Comment: i tried out using the first lib and ended up with something like this: `code` (SEQUENCE {
   OCTETSTRING 313030
   PrintableString 'I am a String'
   INTEGER 123
   BOOLEAN TRUE
})`code`        Im new to ASN1 and now im wondering how my communication partner could know what kind ob object im sending to him